# Guava CacheBuilder - ensuring parent objects are in the cache if their children are

Tags: java, caching, guava

We're using a cache which is currently configured like this:

```
private final Cache<K, V> storage = CacheBuilder.<K, V>newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(100)
    .removalListener(new RemovalListener<K, V>() { ... })
    .build();
```

When we insert a node, we also touch all its ancestors so that a node's "last used" value would always be more recent than its children which are in the cache.

But what we're finding is that it still somehow evicts the parents when the children are still in the cache. This is a problem for us, because the children maintain a reference to the parent and the `RemovalListener` closes the parent, which closes file handles required to continue using its descendants.

Is there a proper way to keep this sort of dependency?

If there isn't, is there are least some value for the maximum size which I can put in to ensure that it won't evict entries prematurely? We're passing 100 for the maximum size and some of the items it evicts were in the top 10 most recently used items.

Comment: Can't you handle this logic in the `RemovalListener`? Like "get all children, remove them"? Guava does not guarantee that the oldest entries are removed first: "The cache will **try** to evict entries that haven't been used recently or very often."

Comment: If I do it in the RemovalListener then a put() operation would sometimes result in removing the item you are putting in.